# Android mouse mirroring over multiple devices

Tags: android, mouse, mirror

This isn't a coding question but I couldn't think of any other community that would be able to answer this question.

My problem is that I have a couple different android devices, I was wondering if there's any applications or any methods of being able to control all the devices at once (assuming that on all devices the same applications will be running in the same location on screen) from only one devices or from my computer. (All devices are wifi enabled).

Comment: There is always http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Chris I was trying to achieve something similar at one point: [See Here](http://superuser.com/questions/367276/would-a-usb-hub-work-in-reverse) fwiw I never found a hardware solution that would allow a single input device to replicate its signals across many computers(or android devices).